# Prove that multiplying and dividing by same number is identity

Tags: dafny

I'm stuck with trying to prove the following lemma:

```
lemma MulDivIsId(a: nat, b: nat)
requires b > 0
ensures a * b / b == a
{
}
```

I tried to help the verifier by showing that b over b is 1, and also tried mentioning that `a * b / b` equals `a * (b / b)`, which it however couldn't prove. How can I prove this? Are there general steps that usually help when proving lemmas involving integer division/natural number division (which in Dafny is truncating division)?

Comment: I'm not a Dafny user, but parts of your code seem redundant, for example, why do you have `requires b > 0`? when `b` is `nat` ("natural numbers") which are already defined as being non-negative? Also, arithmetic on `nat` isn't the same as arithmetic over Reals or Rationals (just like how IEEE floats can't be used to model true reals). Finally (and chiefly), division isn't defined for natural-numbers (though truncated-division and division-with-remainder are possible alternatives, your post doesn't say you're using either of those).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In Dafny, `nat` on its own includes 0 and it uses truncating division. If I used type `real` instead of `nat`, Dafny could verify the lemma automatically, so the truncating division is what makes it hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular lemma is proved in Dafny standard library [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/libraries/blob/master/src/dafny/NonlinearArithmetic/DivMod.dfy#L763). This requires stating additional lemma about multiplication and division. But hopefully proof is easy to follow.

---

Edit: See code listed below to prove this manually

```
lemma DivModLemma(k: nat, n: nat)
   requires n > 0
   ensures n * (k / n) + k % n == k
{}

lemma ZeroLemma(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires a > 0
  requires a * b == 0
  ensures b == 0
{}

lemma CancelLemma(a: nat, b: nat, c: nat)
   requires c > 0
   requires c * a == c * b
   ensures a == b
{
  if c == 1 {}
  else {
    calc {
      c * a  - c * b == 0;
      c * (a - b) == 0;
      { ZeroLemma(c, a - b); }
      a - b == 0;
      a == b;
    }
  }
}

lemma ModZeroLemma(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires b > 0
  requires a % b == 0
  ensures a == (a / b) * b
{}

lemma ExactDivisionLemma(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires b > 0
  requires exists m :: m * b == a
  ensures a % b == 0
{
  DivModLemma(a, b);
  assert b * (a / b) + a % b == a;
  var m :| m * b == a;

  assert b * (a / b) + a % b == m * b;
  assert ((a / b) - m) * b + a % b == 0;
  assert 0 <= a % b < b;

  if a / b - m == 0 {}
  else if a / b - m < 0 {
    assert (a / b - m) <= -1;
  }
  else {
    assert (a / b - m) >= 1;
  }
}

lemma ReminderLemma(a: nat, b: nat, c : nat)
  requires c > 0
  requires a % c == 0 && b % c == 0
  ensures (a + b) % c == 0
{
  ModZeroLemma(a, c);
  ModZeroLemma(b, c);
  assert a + b == (a / c) * c + (b / c) * c;
  assert a + b == (a / c + b / c) * c;
  ExactDivisionLemma(a + b, c);
}

lemma ModLemma(a: nat, b: nat, c: nat)
  requires c > 0
  requires a % c == 0 && b % c == 0
  ensures (a + b) / c == a / c + b / c
{
  DivModLemma(a + b, c);
  assert c * ((a + b) / c) + (a + b) % c == (a + b);
  ReminderLemma(a, b, c);
  assert c * ((a + b) / c) == (a + b);
  DivModLemma(a, c);
  assert c * (a / c) + a % c == a;
  assert c * (a / c) == a;
  DivModLemma(b, c);
  assert c * (b / c) + b % c == b;
  assert c * (b / c) == b;
  assert c * (a / c) + c * (b / c) == a + b;
  assert c * (a / c + b / c) == a + b;
  assert c * ((a + b) / c) == c * (a / c + b / c);
  CancelLemma((a + b) / c, a / c + b / c, c);
}

lemma MulDivId(a: nat, b: nat)
  requires b > 0
  ensures (a * b) / b == a
{
  if a == 0 {}
  else {
    calc {
       (a * b) / b;
       ((a - 1 + 1) * b ) / b;
       ((a - 1) * b + b ) / b;
       {
         ExactDivisionLemma((a-1) * b, b);
         ModLemma((a - 1) * b, b, b);
       }
       (a - 1) * b / b + b / b;
       { MulDivId(a - 1, b); }
       a - 1 + 1;
       a;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, that's not as easy to follow as I hoped, given that that library is written not to make use of Z3's builtin integer arithmetic reasoning. I wonder how the proof would be written normally, without `--disable-nonlinear-arithmetic`.

Comment: Since this is standard Dafny library, I am assuming it should include most non-intrusive way to prove this fact. I tried to proof but I run into problem of needing conclusion of proof to complete proof. May be I need to think more. Regarding disable-nonlinear-arithemetic, it is probably disabled to make proof stable.

Comment: Added code snippet to prove this manually